# Cannot convert string value 'NO_ARTIFACT_FILE' to an enum value of type

Tags: javascript

> Cannot convert string value 'NO_ARTIFACT_FILE' to an enum value of
> type 'com.android.builder.model.v2.ide.LibraryType' (valid case
> insensitive values: PROJECT, ANDROID_LIBRARY, JAVA_LIBRARY, RELOCATED)

How to solve this?

try several time but same problem.

Comment: Is this question based around Java instead of Javascript?